# Why does git checkout -b {branchname} allow me to create a new branch when I have not yet committed?

Tags: git

Okay. This has me confused. I just initialized an empty git repository running the command `git init`. I then added a file to git's object store i.e. `git add .` I attempted to create a branch i.e. `git branch {branchname}`. I get an error because based on what I have read I cannot created a branch without having committed at least once. Okay. I'll bite. So I then try `git checkout -b {branchname}`. It appears to have worked i.e. I am transported to the branch I just created. Whoa? I try `git checkout master` and I get the error `error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Why was I able to create a new branch and not checkout the `master branch`? What am I overlooking or have not understood?

Answer (score 1):

`master`, like `origin` or `upstream`, is a convention, not a requirement. Since you have no commits in `master`, you have no refs for it either. `HEAD` is pointing to a ref that does not yet exist. When you run `git checkout -b branch`, you ask git to:

1. Duplicate the ref your `HEAD` points to.
2. Point your `HEAD` to the new ref.

Since your `HEAD` points to a nonexistent ref, you duplicate nothing and end up still pointing to nothing. As long as you continue to switch branches without committing, this will be the case.

Once you've made your first commit everything changes. Now that you've made a commit, you have a ref for your current `HEAD` to point to. The next time you create a branch, there's a ref to duplicate, so the branch won't disappear next time you switch.

Example(ish):

```
git init
touch test
git add test
# There are no refs at this point, but HEAD is pointing to the nonexistent refs/heads/master
git checkout -b new_branch
git checkout master # fails, no refs (for master)
git checkout -b new_branch2
git checkout new_branch # fails, no refs (for new_branch)
git commit -m "Initial commit." 
# Now you have a ref for new_branch2, but not yet for any other branches.
git checkout -b new_branch3 # new_branch2's ref is duplicated
git checkout new_branch2 # success, you made a commit in this branch so it has a ref
git checkout new_branch3 # success, you made a commit in new_branch2 which this branch's ref is also pointing to.
git checkout master # failure, until you run with '-b' master doesn't have any refs yet.
```

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me initially...

```
durrantm.../play$ mkdir ggg
durrantm.../play$ cd ggg
durrantm.../ggg$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/durrantm/play/ggg/.git/
durrantm.../ggg$ git checkout -b newy
fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born
```

...until yes, I did an initial commit on master:

```
durrantm.../ggg$ vi x.x
durrantm.../ggg$ git add .
durrantm.../ggg$ git commit -m"Initial Commit"
[master (root-commit) 75bcf19] Initial Commit
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 x.x
durrantm.../ggg$ git checkout -b abc
Switched to a new branch 'abc'
durrantm.../ggg$
```